# Detect (and override) keypress of F1 key even if another app has focus

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, keyboard, keypress

How is it possible, in a Win32 application coded in Visual C++, to **detect the keypress of the <kbd>F1</kbd> key** and restore/maximize its GUI when this happens?

This key should be detected **even if another application has focus**, and override the usual F1 "help" window behaviour.

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Test";
    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {

        // Should it be detected here ? //

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait. My program wants to do this too. Please don't install your program on a machine where mine runs. Thanks.

Comment: formally you can use `RegisterHotKey(hwnd, <id>, 0, VK_F1);` and you will got `WM_HOTKEY` when F1 pressed. but if no another app also try register F1 hot key

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Too bad I'm making an "Options" dialog that allows to customize the desired shortcut...

Comment: @RbMm Some programs are able to override such keypresses like Autohotkey regardless which program has focus, etc.

Comment: It's RegisterHotKey that does this. Make sure your uninstall program is well tested. It will get a lot of use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: will this override other program's F1 ?

Comment: @Basj - [`RegisterHotKey fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have already been registered by another hot key.`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx). and yes, override

Comment: Wonderful, it works! Does someone want to post it as an answer, for future reference, or should I do it?

Comment: Normally this is bad usability.

Comment: You may also be interested in SetWindowHookEx() with WH_KEYBOARD_LL, which will call your LowLeveKeyboardProc() each time an keyboard event occours. See MSDN on that for details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by @RbMm, the solution is:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Test";
    WNDCLASS wc = { };
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME, L"Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    RegisterHotKey(hWnd, 100, 0, VK_F1);  // here we go!

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY)
            // Do something here

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See also [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx).